# google cloud secret is there or not

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-secret-manager

I created two secrets one with

> --data-file=-

and one without above flags,

So first was created as followes

```
echo -n "Demo" | gcloud secrets create First-password --data-file=-
```

Second was created as

```
echo -n "mySuperSecert" | gcloud secrets create xyz-password
```

Now when i try to retrieve the xyz-password , it reports

> ERROR: (gcloud.secrets.versions.access) NOT_FOUND: Secret
> [projects/ProjectNumber/secrets/XYZ-password] not found or has no
> versions.

A screenshot is attached below, actual project number and variable name is hidden as i used closed one's name in example, so in screenshot it says XYZ.

How to access this secret now or delete it, It shows up when '**gcloud secrets list**' but when actually try to get value it fails, and the way to reproduce the issue is not to specify

> --data-file=-

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have 2 types of resources: the secret and the versions

In the first case, the gcloud CLI conveniently create the secret and the first version with the value your provided (data-file)

In the second one, the gcloud CLI only created the secret, not the version. Therefore, if you try to access the secret value, there is no value! It's totally file.

You can delete the secret if you want, but you won't be able to get the `mySuperSecert` value, because it has not been stored.